# Why does the Gamma function interpolate $(n-1)!$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, special-functions, gamma-function

Why does the Gamma function interpolate $(n-1)!$ and not $n!$ instead? What is the historical reason?

Comment: $\Gamma(s+1)=s\Gamma(s)$ for all $s$, and $\Gamma(1)=1$.

Comment: [Very related.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267989)

Comment: @i707107 You should write that as answer. Just, for all $s>0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Historically, it is [Legendre's "fault"](http://www.archive.org/stream/mmoiresdelinst10inst#page/476/mode/2up).
Before that, several analytical expressions to interpolate $n!$ where introduced by Bernoulli and Euler and Gauß introduced $\Pi(x)$ as notation such that $\Pi(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$, but this has not become dominant, cf. J.M.'s comment above.