# Generalised factorial

Tags: functions

When generalizing the factorial, we often refer to the gamma function, which gives $(n-1)!$ for $\Gamma(n)$. Why do we not use the Pi function instead, which provides the factorial of the input? Is there a formatting issue with it or is it something else?

Comment: There's no inherent issue with it; it's just that some formulas appear nicer with one as opposed to the other, and the gamma function is also a bit more known.

Examples of formulas more pleasant with the gamma function are the reflection  formula for $\sin(z)$, 

$$\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}$$

as opposed to

$$\Pi(z-1) \Pi(-z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi z)}
\implies
\Pi(z) \Pi(-z) = \frac{\pi z}{\sin(\pi z)} = \frac{1}{\operatorname{sinc}(z)}$$

[cont.]

Comment: which does not so clearly denote a reflection. Though I suppose one could prefer the latter formula in terms of $\Pi$ since $\operatorname{sinc}(z)$ (or $\operatorname{sinc}(\pi z)$ since definitions vary) is itself useful and the formula is still aesthetically pleasing in some sense.

Another is the definition of the beta function,

$$\mathrm{B}(x,y) := \frac{\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)} = \frac{\Pi(x-1) \Pi(y-1)}{\Pi(x+y-1)}$$

so in turn

$$\frac{xy}{x+y} \mathrm{B}(x,y) = \frac{\Pi(x) \Pi(y)}{\Pi(x+y)}$$

for which I can foresee no justification for the use of $\Pi$. [cont.]

Comment: Another thought is that, since $\Pi(x)$ is meant to align to $x!$ anyways on the nonnegative integers, one could just say "define $x!$ as the analytic continuation of the usual definition that is given for $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$" and just roll with that.

Some more discussion on MathOverflow is [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20960/why-is-the-gamma-function-shifted-from-the-factorial-by-1), and on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/267989/the-gamma-function-and-the-pi-function).